# Select query to cast and count error

Tags: sql, t-sql

So, I have this query and I would like to know why I am getting an error. I cannot find anything suspicious:

```
SELECT CAST(((COUNT(FileSize) * 100.0) / (SELECT NULLIF(COUNT(*), 0) FROM InfoFile))
AS DECIMAL(10, 2)) AS[Percentage(%)]
```

The error is:

> Invalid column name 'FileSize'.

So do you have any idea why this is happening?

Comment: Already got it. Forget about the last from. Thank you a lot @TheGameiswar

Comment: `select 
 cast((COUNT(FileSize) * 100.0)/ NULLIF(COUNT(*), 0) as cecimal(10,2))
 from
 infofile`

Answer (score 0):

Because the `FROM` clause is in a subquery, so the column name is not recognized.

Presumably, you intend something like this:

```
SELECT (COUNT(FileSize) * 100.0) / NULLIF(COUNT(*), 0) AS[Percentage(%)]
FROM InfoFile;
```

Actually, an alternative method would be:

```
select avg(case when filesize is not null then 100.0 else 0 end) as Percentage
from infoFile;
```